# How to let code in block execute first

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, multithreading

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{
    __block UIImage *image = [UIImage new];
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imageURL] options:nil];
    PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        image = result;
    }];
    return image;
}
```

the code in block "image = result" execute after code out of block "return image" , so it always return nil.
How can i make the code in block execute first. Use thread or NSOperation or GCD?

Comment: Use completion block. You just can't synchronously return the result from asynchronous call (without blocking UI and without time travel).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromURL:(NSURL *)imageURL{
     __block UIImage *image = [UIImage new];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imageURL] options:nil];
        PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;
        PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
        [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            image = result;
        }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             return image;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: it will get a error , build failed . How to fix it?

Comment: you cannot 'return image' in a block when this block has no return . Like function , block can also return value , but block 'dispatch_async' has no return